# SQL find min & max range within dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns:

```
contactId  (int)  
interval   (int)  
date (smalldate)
```

small sample data:

```
1,120,'12/02/2010'  
1,121,'12/02/2010'  
1,122,'12/02/2010'  
1,123,'12/02/2010'  
1,145,'12/02/2010'  
1,146,'12/02/2010'  
1,147,'12/02/2010'  
2,122,'12/02/2010'  
2,123,'12/02/2010'  
2,124,'12/02/2010'  
2,320,'12/02/2010'  
2,321,'12/02/2010'  
2,322,'12/02/2010'  
2,450,'12/02/2010'  
2,451,'12/02/2010'
```

how/is it possible - to get sql to return columns "contactId, minInterval, maxInterval, date", e.g

```
1,120,123,'12/02/2010'  
1,145,147,'12/02/2010'  
2,122,124,'12/02/2010'  
2,320,322,'12/02/2010'  
2,450,451,'12/02/2010'
```

hopefully this makes sense, basically i'm looking to figure out the min/max range of the intervals by provider & date for the range where they increment by one... once there is a break in the interval incrementer (e.g. more than one) then it would indicate a new min/max range...

any help is greatly appreciated :)

here is my exact SQL table setup:

```
create table availability  
(  
 Id  (int)  
 ProviderId (int)  
 IntervalId (int)  
 Date (date)  
)
```

sample data

```
providerid,intervalid,date  
1128,108,2010-12-27  
1128,109,2010-12-27  
1128,110,2010-12-27  
1128,111,2010-12-27  
1128,112,2010-12-27  
1128,113,2010-12-27  
1128,114,2010-12-27  
1128,120,2010-12-27  
1128,121,2010-12-27  
1128,122,2010-12-27  
1128,123,2010-12-27  
1128,124,2010-12-27  
1128,125,2010-12-27  
1213,108,2010-12-27  
1213,109,2010-12-27  
1213,110,2010-12-27  
1213,111,2010-12-27  
1213,112,2010-12-27  
1213,113,2010-12-27  
1213,114,2010-12-27  
1213,115,2010-12-27  
1213,232,2010-12-27  
1213,233,2010-12-27  
1213,234,2010-12-27  
3954,198,2010-12-27  
3954,199,2010-12-27  
3954,200,2010-12-27  
3954,201,2010-12-27   
3954,202,2010-12-27  
3954,203,2010-12-27   
3954,204,2010-12-27  
3954,205,2010-12-27  
3954,206,2010-12-27  
3954,207,2010-12-27  
3954,208,2010-12-27  
3954,209,2010-12-27  
3954,210,2010-12-27  
3954,211,2010-12-27  
3954,212,2010-12-27  
3954,213,2010-12-27  
3954,214,2010-12-27  
3954,215,2010-12-27  
3954,216,2010-12-27  
3954,217,2010-12-27  
3954,218,2010-12-27  
3954,229,2010-12-27  
3954,230,2010-12-27  
3954,231,2010-12-27  
3954,232,2010-12-27  
3954,233,2010-12-27  
3954,234,2010-12-27  
1128,108,2010-12-28  
1128,109,2010-12-28  
1128,110,2010-12-28  
1128,111,2010-12-28  
1128,112,2010-12-28  
1128,113,2010-12-28  
1128,114,2010-12-28  
1128,115,2010-12-28  
1128,116,2010-12-28  
3954,186,2010-12-28  
3954,187,2010-12-28  
3954,188,2010-12-28  
3954,189,2010-12-28  
3954,190,2010-12-28  
3954,213,2010-12-28  
3954,214,2010-12-28  
3954,215,2010-12-28  
3954,216,2010-12-28  
3954,217,2010-12-28  
3954,218,2010-12-28  
3954,219,2010-12-28  
3954,220,2010-12-28  
3954,221,2010-12-28  
3954,222,2010-12-28
```

sample result using current sql within answers:

```
1062,180,180,2010-12-20  
1062,179,179,2010-12-20  
1062,178,178,2010-12-20  
1062,177,177,2010-12-20  
1062,176,176,2010-12-20  
1062,175,175,2010-12-20  
1062,174,174,2010-12-20  
1062,173,173,2010-12-20  
1062,172,172,2010-12-20  
1062,171,171,2010-12-20  
1062,170,170,2010-12-20  
1062,169,169,2010-12-20    
1062,168,168,2010-12-20  
1062,167,167,2010-12-20  
1062,166,166,2010-12-20  
1062,165,165,2010-12-20  
1062,164,164,2010-12-20  
1062,163,163,2010-12-20  
1062,162,162,2010-12-20  
1062,161,161,2010-12-20  
1062,160,160,2010-12-20  
1062,159,159,2010-12-20  
1062,158,158,2010-12-20  
1062,157,157,2010-12-20  
1062,156,156,2010-12-20  
1062,155,155,2010-12-20  
1062,154,154,2010-12-20  
1062,153,153,2010-12-20  
1062,152,152,2010-12-20  
1062,151,151,2010-12-20  
1062,150,150,2010-12-20  
1062,149,149,2010-12-20  
1062,148,148,2010-12-20  
1062,147,147,2010-12-20  
1062,146,146,2010-12-20  
1062,145,145,2010-12-20  
1062,144,144,2010-12-20  
1062,143,143,2010-12-20  
1062,142,142,2010-12-20  
1062,141,141,2010-12-20  
1062,140,140,2010-12-20  
1062,139,139,2010-12-20  
1062,138,138,2010-12-20  
1062,137,137,2010-12-20  
1062,136,136,2010-12-20  
1062,135,135,2010-12-20  
1062,134,134,2010-12-20  
1062,133,133,2010-12-20  
1062,132,132,2010-12-20  
1062,131,131,2010-12-20  
1062,130,130,2010-12-20  
1062,129,129,2010-12-20  
1062,128,128,2010-12-20  
1062,127,127,2010-12-20  
1062,126,126,2010-12-20  
1062,125,125,2010-12-20  
1062,124,124,2010-12-20  
1062,123,123,2010-12-20  
1062,122,122,2010-12-20  
1062,121,121,2010-12-20  
1062,120,120,2010-12-20  
1062,119,119,2010-12-20  
1062,118,118,2010-12-20  
1062,117,117,2010-12-20  
1062,116,116,2010-12-20  
1062,115,115,2010-12-20  
1062,114,114,2010-12-20  
1062,113,113,2010-12-20  
1062,112,112,2010-12-20
```

Comment: What database are you using? Gaps and Islands solutions can be different for different back ends

Comment: Is it correct that by "provider" you are referring to the contactID field?

Comment: my bad, yes provider is the contactid - and i'm using sql server. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `SQL Server`, `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL`:

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  t.*, interval - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contactID, date ORDER BY interval) AS sr
        FROM    mytable t
        )
SELECT  contactID, date, MIN(interval), MAX(interval)
FROM    q
GROUP BY
        date, contactID, sr
ORDER BY
        date, contactID, sr
```

**Update:**

With your test data I get this output:

```
WITH    mytable (providerId, intervalId, date) AS
        (
        SELECT  1128,108,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,109,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,110,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,111,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,112,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,113,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,114,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,120,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,121,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,122,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,123,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,124,'2010-12-27' UNION ALL
        SELECT  1128,125,'2010-12-27'
        ),
        q AS
        (
        SELECT  t.*, intervalId - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY providerId, date ORDER BY intervalId) AS sr
        FROM    mytable t
        )
SELECT  providerId, date, MIN(intervalId), MAX(intervalId)
FROM    q
GROUP BY
        date, providerId, sr
ORDER BY
        date, providerId, sr

1128  2010-12-27  108  114
1128  2010-12-27  120  125
```

, i. e. exactly what you were after.

Are you sure you are using the query correctly? Are you having duplicates on `(providerId, intervalId, date)`?

Comment: thanks for the answer - i'm not sure I follow the columns, e.g. small, sample, etc. how would they relate to the columns in my table?

Comment: @Andre: sorry, you post was formatted so that I thought `small`, `sample` and `data` are the headers of your columns :)

Comment: I'm a newbie here, still learning how to format posts properly - thanks :)

Comment: @Andre: BTW, if the date changes, does it break the interval series?

Comment: the table to query will have 4 weeks worth of data in it, for each day the intervals can be only between 1 and 288 - it represents a full days worth of time where each interval is a 5 minute increment. does that make sense?

Comment: @Andre: not much. Say we have these records: `2, 451, '12/02/2010'` and `2, 452, '13/02/2010'` (note the change in the `date` field). Do they go to one continuous range or different?

Comment: @Quassnoi you probably need to add date to the CTE's select clause

Comment: when i run your sql it gives me an error saying "invalid column 'date'"

Comment: in your example of the two records but with different dates then they would be two different records - the min/max range is on a per-day basis

Comment: hmmm - that seems to run without error, however does not seem to return the desired result. maybe an error on my end... but it returns a lot more rows that it should - also how would i then get it in order : by date, contactid ? Seems like i need to read up on SQL partition!

Comment: @Andre: please post a sample dataset and the output of the query over this dataset. `Id` as such should not be a problem since it's not used in the query at all.

Comment: updated original question with exact table layout on my end and sample data that goes across to days - hope that helps. thanks again!

Comment: @Andre: please post the output of the query too.

Comment: here is part of the output - is there an easier way to post output? is there a way to attach a text file?

1128 204 204 2010-12-21  
1128 203 203 2010-12-21  
1128 202 202 2010-12-21  
1128 201 201 2010-12-21  
1128 200 200 2010-12-21
1128 199 199 2010-12-21
1128 198 198 2010-12-21
1128 197 197 2010-12-21
1128 196 196 2010-12-21
1128 195 195 2010-12-21

Comment: @Andre: just update your original post, in the same way you posted the input.

Comment: ok thanks a bunch - I will give this a try, probably just something I was doing wrong on my end. Again, many thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

it's probably possible to do this with a SQL query alone, but it will probably be a bit mind-boggling. Basically a subquery to find places where it increments by one, joined to the original dataset, with tons of other logic in there. That's my impression at least.

If I were you,

If this is a one-time deal, don't care about performance and just iterate over it and do the calculation 'manually'.

If this is a production dataset and you need to do this operation on a frequent / automated / performance-intensive setting, then rearrange the original dataset to make this kind of query easier.

Hope one of those options is available to you.